# Find a column that contains a specific string from another column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have 2 data frames. One called cuartos (rooms in English) and another called paredes (walls in English) They have room temperatures and walls temperatures. I want to create a new data frame with the temperature difference between each wall and its room. For example

Room name = 2_APTO_1
Walls of the room = 2_APTO_1.FACE2, 2_APTO_1.FACE3 and 2_APTO_1.FACE4

The new data frame should be something like

```
2_APTO_1.FACE2 = 2_APTO_1.FACE2 - 2_APTO_1
2_APTO_1.FACE3 = 2_APTO_1.FACE3 - 2_APTO_1
2_APTO_1.FACE4 = 2_APTO_1.FACE4 - 2_APTO_1 ....
```

[image]

[image]

I tried this:

1. get a list of paredes and cuartos columns

   col_names_paredes= paredes.columns.tolist()

   col_names_cuartos= cuartos.columns.tolist()
2. Check if col_names_paredes has col_names_cuartos names in it

for i in col_names_cuartos:
for k in col_names_paredes:
if col_names_paredes[k] in col_names_cuartos[i]:
print(k)

I got this error

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `for i in col_names_cuartos`, `i` will take column names values, not indice values that you would obtain with `for i in range(len(col_names_cuartos))`.

So you can use the following code instead :

```
for col_cuartos in col_names_cuartos: 
    for col_paredes in col_names_paredes: 
        if col_paredes in col_cuartos: 
            print(col_paredes)
```